# Date Validation in Visualforce/Apex without JS

Tags: apex, visualforce, date

For a date field , I know I can put validate like this :

```
<apex:outputText label=" Date" value="{0,date, MM'/'dd'/'/YYYY}" >
                        <apex:param value="{!item.Date__c}" />
```

But this might have loopholes in it like 02/03/2017 entered manually may maean different in US and say UK format . 
Is there any other validation that can be added through VF page or apex code ?
Not asking about any JS solution.

Comment: You can display it differently based on the user locale. Not sure what you mean by validation as this is not an input?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant `<apex:inputText... />` instead of `<apex:outputText .../>`. You could use jquery [datetimepicker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/). Download the library, include in your VF page, apply `dateTimeField` class to your `<apex:inputText.../>` and execute below code on page load:

```
function setPickers(){
        $('.dateTimeField').datetimepicker({
            lang: 'en',
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
        });
    }
```

You'll have a really nice-looking jquery-based datetime pickers. Nevertheless it would be good to check data in apex too:

```
try {
    Date dt = Date.parse(dateFromVFPage);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Not a date!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks EvAzi . Talking about the Apex solution . Wouldn't the Salesforce internal message be shown before the custom code that I will be putting?

Comment: My scenario - For a date field user enter 9/9/209 it is changed to 9/9/2209 even before Save

Comment: @SFDCRookie quite don't understand your question. If user enters 9/9/209, salesforce will show "Not a date!".

Comment: In any datepicker field ,  if I enter 9/9/178 manually , Salesforce will change it to 9/9/2178